# Why in a DFA the empty string distinguishes any accept state from any reject state?

Tags: computer-science, automata

Often I read this sentence about DFA:

> The empty string $\epsilon$ distinguishes any accept state from any
>   reject state.

Here the source: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/520-S08/handouts/Lec7.pdf

I don't understand the above statement, since by definition a DFA can't have $\epsilon$ transitions. Please can you explain me better? Many thanks!

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: @mrp I have added the source in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That claim has nothing to do with $\epsilon$-transitions.  What is says intuitively is that even before you read any input letter, you can tell an accepting state from a non-accepting state.

In minimizing DFAs, we look for *indistinguishable* states.  Two states are indistinguishable if the same language is accepted starting from both.  To compute the indistinguishable pairs, we define $k$-indistinguishable states; that is, those states from which the words of length up to $k$ accepted from the two states are exactly the same.  As a special case, two states are $0$-indistinguishable if and only if they are either both accepting or both rejecting.  This is what those lecture notes presumably talk about.